# Unicode characters not saving with Access front end linked to sql table

Tags: sql, ms-access, unicode, linked-tables

I have an old access database that I have converted to Office 2010 format and then moved the one data table to SQL.  There is only one form that is associated with the one linked table.

Once it was all done I compared the data from before and after and found that all the ≤ had been converted to =.  I had mistakenly set the field as varchar so I updated it to nvarchar.  I then inserted some corrected data via SQL Server Mgt Studio and all looked good.

The issue is that if I enter ≤ symbols via access they look fine, but once I close and reopen the front end they aren't there.  They seem to be being converted to = when access writes to the sql back end table.

My research says that it may be that the ODBC connection is stuffing up the Unicode character, but then other places say it should be fine.  I am not doing the update via sql so I can't try the N in front of unicode text.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try deleting the Linked Table in Access and then re-create it. I was able to reproduce your issue in that after I changed the column type from `varchar` to `nvarchar` my `≤` characters were still getting changed to `=`. However, after I deleted and re-created the table link in Access the problem went away.

Comment: Your the man Gord.  That trick worked well.  I've since made another change to the table and removing the linked table and re-adding worked again.  Cheers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment from Gord was right on the mark.  When you make changes to the SQL table in the back end Access will not update the linked table.  You need to remove it and re-add it.

Just use the same name as before and everything will work fine.